# Why is the PLL not locking? Is my clock configuration correct?

Tags: c, configuration, stm32, clock

I am using the stm32l412kb for UART communication. I am trying to configure the USART2 peripheral clock to a 72MHz frequency. The stm32, after reset, uses the MSI at 4MHz, which I then use the PLL to extend to 72MHz when reaching the peripheral.

The code holds at the first PLLRDY check, as the PLL I assume is not locking. Could this be due to a too high a frequency output? Have I configure everything correctly? How do I know that the PLL is then being used instead of the 4MHz MSI, or the 24MHz HSE?

'''

```
void configureClocks(){
/*Clock Configuration
 * The MSI (at 4MHz) is used as system clock source after startup from Reset.
 * */

/*Turning on the medium speed internal clock (making sure it's on)*/
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_MSION;
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_MSIPLLEN;

/*Waiting until clock is ready*/
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_MSIRDY));

/*Selecting the MSI (0010) as the MCU clock output*/
RCC->CFGR   &= RCC_CFGR_MCOSEL_Msk;
RCC->CFGR   |= (0b0010<<RCC_CFGR_MCOSEL_Pos);


/*Turn off PLL to allow to make changes*/
RCC->CR &= ~(RCC_CR_PLLON_Msk);


/*Make sure PLL is locked*/
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));

/*At 4Mhz, (4*36/2 = 72Mhz)*/
RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Msk | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Msk);
RCC->PLLCFGR |= (2 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos) | (36 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos);

/*Turning back on the PLL clock*/
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;


/*Waiting until clock is ready*/
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));

/*Selecting the PLL (0101) as the microcontroller clock output*/
RCC->CFGR   &= RCC_CFGR_MCOSEL_Msk;
RCC->CFGR   |= (0b0101<<RCC_CFGR_MCOSEL_Pos);

/*Enabling the USART2 peripheral clock.*/
RCC->APB1ENR1 &= ~(RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN_Msk);
RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (0b1 << RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN_Pos);

/*Enabling the GPIOA port peripheral clock*/
RCC->AHB2ENR &= ~(RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN_Msk);
RCC->AHB2ENR |= (0b1 << RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN_Pos);
return;
}
```

'''

Your responses are always much appreciated,

Many thanks,

Harry

Update, thanks to comments:
The first PLL check has been changed from:

```
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_MSIRDY));
```

to:

```
while(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_MSIRDY);
```

However, the PLL check still gets stuck on the second one.

Comment: You have no PLL source selected. Please see update to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/b0/ac/3e/8f/6d/21/47/af/DM00151940/files/DM00151940.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00151940.pdf) (pdf) section 6.2.3 "MSI clock", "Hardware auto calibration with LSE (PLL-mode)" and section 6.4.1 "Clock control register (RCC_CR)"

There is in your code:

```
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_MSIPLLEN;
```

But before enabling PLL mode on the MSI clock you have two things to be done:

1. External low-frequency resonator or oscillator should be installed (e.g. 32768Hz clock quartz)
2. As said in the **Bit 2 MSIPLLEN** description: *MSIPLLEN must be enabled after LSE is enabled (LSEON enabled) and ready (LSERDY set
   by hardware).There is a hardware protection to avoid enabling MSIPLLEN if LSE is not
   ready.*

So, if you have LSE installed, first you have to turn it on, and wait until it ready:

```
RCC->BDCR |= (RCC_BDCR_LSEON);
/*Make sure LSE is ready*/
while(!(RCC->BDCR & RCC_BDCR_LSERDY));
```

But probably you don't have to use PLL function of the MSI, because USART much more tolerant to frequency deviations. Then MSI-PLL mode should be kept disabled.

STM32 MCUs have some protection mechanics to avoid wrongly switch the clock source. Some bits cannot be set until clock source is ready, or cannot be cleared if the clock source is in use. They are described in the reference manual in bit descriptions.

So, please, carefully compare all steps you're doing to the manual.

**UPD** 
As pointed out in another answer

```
/*Turn off PLL to allow to make changes*/
RCC->CR &= ~(RCC_CR_PLLON_Msk);


/*Make sure PLL is locked*/
while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));
```

You cannot have PLL locked when it is disabled. So, the while-loop will run forever.

**UPD2**

Before enabling the PLL you forget to set up it's source (bits PLLSRC in PLLCFGR). I.e.:

```
// set MSI as the source for PLL
RCC->PLLCFGR = (RCC->PLLCFGR & ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_Msk) | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_MSI;
```

Comment: A huge thank you for this help. I had certainly missed setting the MSI as the PLLSRC. The code now runs well!

Answer (score 2):

After disabling the PLL with `RCC->CR &= ~(RCC_CR_PLLON_Msk);` **wait until `PLLRDY` is cleared**.

Your code does the opposite, waits until `PLLRDY` is set, meaning it's locked. But you've just disabled it, so it's not going to lock.

After setting up `PLLCFGR`, turn it back on, and wait until `PLLRDY` is set. This part looks OK in the code.

---

When the PLL is running at the required speed, you should set the **System clock switch** (`RCC_CFGR_SW`) to PLL instead of the Microcontroller clock output to have your system run on the PLL clock.

Microcontroller clock output does something else. It can be connected to an external pin, to *output* the clock signal for using it outside the MCU, e.g. to synchronise several MCUs.

Comment: Many thanks, the code no longer sticks there. The code does not get past the second check however.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Cube to see the clock tree. I also use registers - but that tool is very convenient and it prevents many stupid errors as it will let you know if the values are outside the recommended ones.

[image]

PS it should be a comment but I wanted to put the picture. So please do not UV or accept

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is what I usually use but I am trying to learn how to configure without this.

Comment: I am not saying to use HAL to initialize - just to see the values :)